# How can I separate a string that contains whitespace between words and punctuation into sentences?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
string = "Mr . john bought greatsite . com for 1 . 5 million dollars , i . e . he paid a lot for it . Did he mind ? Steve jones jr . thinks he didn't . In any case , this isn't true ... Well , with a probability of  . 9 it isn't . What a great site ! I really loved it !!! Did you ???"
```

I need to split it into sentences like this:

```
Mr . john bought greatsite . com for 1 . 5 million dollars , i . e . he paid a lot for it . 
Did he mind ? 
Steve jones jr . thinks he didn't .
In any case , this isn't true ...
Well , with a probability of  . 9 it isn't . 
What a great site !
I really loved it !!!
Did you ???
```

and save them into a list of sentences.

I used the following code:

```
sents = re.split(r"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?|\!)\s", input_doc2)
print (sents)
```

The output I get is:

```
    ['mr .', 'smith bought cheapsite .', 'com for 1 .', '5 million dollars , i .', 'e .', 'he paid a lot for it .', 'did he mind ?', 'adam jones jr .', "thinks he didn't .", "in any case , this isn't true ...", 'well , with a probability of  .', "9 it isn't .", 'what a great movie !', 'i loved it .', 'i loved it !!!', 'did you ???', 'i did .!?', 'not really it was bad !', '']
```

Which is wrong. It seems like there is no way around this. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This goes into the realm of NLP, where data on the rules of human grammar is necessary. Building it from regex is not going to work in long run.

Comment: Punctuation followed by a capital letter seems to be the rule for where the next sentence starts.  (note that mr. john is lower case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?|\!)\s(?=[A-Z])
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/3

```
sents = re.split(r"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?|\!)\s(?=[A-Z])", input_doc2)
print (sents)
```